# negative side effect on R dplyr mutate assignment to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

R dplyr mutate code works to change the df$Acres from '10-Jan' to "1 to 10". However, one negative side effect was that when the -> df$Acres assignment was made, the remaining data.frame for column name 'Acres' added 'Acres.Acres', 'Acres.FamilyIncome'. This can be seen in the str(df) below:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Acres = case_when(Acres == "10-Jan" ~ "1 to 10",
                           TRUE ~ Acres)) -> df$Acres


> str(df)
'data.frame':    22745 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ Acres       :'data.frame':    22745 obs. of  18 variables:
  ..$ Acres       : chr  "1 to 10" "1 to 10" "1 to 10" "1 to 10" ...
  ..$ FamilyIncome: int  150 180 280 330 330 480 520 550 1400 1400 ...
  ..$ FamilyType  : chr  "Married" "Female Head" "Female Head" "Female Head" ...
  ..$ NumBedrooms : int  4 3 4 2 3 0 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ NumChildren : int  1 2 0 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ NumPeople   : int  3 4 2 2 2 4 3 2 4 3 ...
  ..$ NumRooms    : int  9 6 8 4 5 1 8 5 9 7 ...
  ..$ NumUnits    : chr  "Single detached" "Single detached" "Single detached" "Single detached" ...
  ..$ NumVehicles : int  1 2 3 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 ...
  ..$ NumWorkers  : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ OwnRent     : chr  "Mortgage" "Rented" "Mortgage" "Rented" ...
  ..$ YearBuilt   : chr  "1950-1959" "Before 1939" "2000-2004" "1950-1959" ...
  ..$ HouseCosts  : int  1800 850 2600 1800 860 700 270 800 710 1500 ...
  ..$ ElectricBill: int  90 90 260 140 150 140 130 1 150 300 ...
  ..$ FoodStamp   : chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
  ..$ HeatingFuel : chr  "Gas" "Oil" "Oil" "Oil" ...
  ..$ Insurance   : int  2500 0 6600 0 660 0 100 0 1000 0 ...
  ..$ Language    : chr  "English" "English" "Other European" "English" ...
 $ FamilyIncome: int  150 180 280 330 330 480 520 550 1400 1400 ...
 $ FamilyType  : chr  "Married" "Female Head" "Female Head" "Female Head" ...
```

The original data.frame had 18 variables, after the dplyr mutate executes, the updated data.frame still has 18 variables, but now with added 'Acres.Acres', 'Acres.FamilyIncome', etc.

Comment: `mutate` returns the whole dataframe with the added column, not just the added column. You should assign it with `df <-`

Comment: Also, looks like you are fixing an import error where it is guessing `1-10` is a date? Is that correct or is the string imported as `"10-Jan"`? You may be able to fix it on the import

Comment: Yes, I am fixing a import date which is "1/10/2019" but imports into the data.frame as "10-Jan", on read.csv I used stringsAsFactors=F

Answer (score 2):

I am exactly not certain what you're trying to achieve here, but why not just save the data frame like this?

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Acres = case_when(Acres == "10-Jan" ~ "1 to 10",
                           TRUE ~ Acres))
```

Comment: that solved it, thanks. sorry, I missed that assignment, having forgot that mutate returns the whole dataframe.